# Windows Server 2008 R2 setup rejects password

Tags: passwords, windows-server-2008-r2, setup

I'm currently installing a Windows Server 2008 R2 system in a VM. As part of the setup process, it asks me to set a password for the Administrator user. But whatever I imagine, it rejects that password and says it donsn't comply with the domain guidelines.

There is no domain. And I'm not in the slightest way interested in security. This is a local test computer which I'll likely throw away when I'm done testing my stuff.

So what's the problem with my passwords? Is 8 characters, numbers and capital letters not enough? I'd expect it to happily accept anything by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 R2 has a default password policy [settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc264456.aspx).  This policy setting checks all new passwords to ensure that they meet basic requirements for strong passwords. By default, the value for this policy setting in Windows Server 2008 is configured to Disabled, but it is set to Enabled in a Windows Server 2008 domain for both environments described in this guide.
When this policy setting is enabled, users must create strong passwords to meet the following minimum requirements:

- Passwords cannot contain the user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed two consecutive characters.
- Passwords must be at least six characters in length.
- Passwords must contain characters from three of the following four categories:
- English uppercase characters (A through Z).
- English lowercase characters (a through z).
- Base 10 digits (0 through 9).
- Non-alphabetic characters (for example, !, $, #, %).

This [article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-password-policy-settings) explains how to change the default settings.

Answer (score 2):

You need (by default) at least 6 chars, and it must contain 3 of the four following character types: Upper case, lower case, number and symbol.  This is the standard/default complexity rule.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc264456.aspx)

Additionally, passwords cannot contain the user’s account name or parts of the user’s full name that exceed two consecutive characters.

Answer (score -1):

For non-domain servers, you can disable password complexity requirements in the group policy editor (not sure about domain servers; if you change it, some over-riding entity will likely change it back automatically, depending on how things are set up).

type gpedit.msc in the run window to access it.

Comment: I think your method might help if the machine were up and running.  But this method wouldn't help during the install process while the password strength requirement is in effect.